# How can I create a Django REST Framework API that connects to an already existing MySQL tables instead of creating them through models.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

instead of this i need to take data directly from table in db i tried using inspectdb but i'm not getting response in the webpage

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created =models.DateTimeFiled(auto_now_add=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,default='0')
    code=models.TextFiled()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')
    class Meta:
       ordering = ('created',)
```

Comment: You can look at Model Meta option called managed : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#managed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add table name in your meta class like this:

```
    class Meta:
       db_table='my_table'
```

also search about the manage command `python manage.py inspectdb`. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/).
It says:

> While Django is best suited for developing new applications, it’s quite possible to integrate it into legacy databases. Django includes a couple of utilities to automate as much of this process as possible.

I think this is answer of your question.

Comment: yeah,thnq implemented and got the response in webpage. Again,i have a query how can i give dynamic input lo the raw queries for fetching data